# Blackberry 6 to Blackberry 5

Tags: blackberry

I have a Blackberry 6 Application and I want to convert it to Blackberry 5 Application is there any way I can make it

Can I some way use Blackberry 6 library in Blackberry 5 OR I have to do it all over again for Blackberry 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you have an app you created for BlackBerry OS6 and now you want it to work on Blackberry OS5 as well.

You cannot use Blackberry OS6 specific libraries in BlackBerry OS5 . There is **nothing** like a **[compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)** like in Android which will allow you to use new APIs on old operating systems. You will have to build your app based on the old OS5 APIs.

Download the Blackberry OS5 JDE and compile your app, it could throw a lot of errors, if not, happy days. If yes, then you need to find third party libraries, or write your own, to create similar functionality in OS5 as well. If you would like to keep the OS6 APIs in your code base, you can use preprocessors to create the binaries for different OS versions.

Using a [preprocessor](http://boldinventions.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=81:javapreprocessorusingeclipse), you can use OS6 APIs for OS6 onwards, and other APIs for OS5 onwards.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse plugin (which I recommend) then you will only need to your Build Config to use Blackberry JRE 5 instead of Blackberry JRE 6. Don't use the JDE if you're not comfortable with it. Unless you are using OS6-specific APIs, you may not have to do much work to make it work on OS5.

Answer (score 0):

You can Compile your code with JRE 5.Then you can use this code in any OS 5,6,7.But you can't use JRE 6 in 5.